# ¿Cómo transferir el resultado completo de una búsqueda de la que solo se han extraído algunos elementos a un UserForm?

Tags: vba

Tengo una hoja excel con muchas columnas incluyendo entre otros el nombre y el apellido. Estoy haciendo una investigación en la hoja y, cuando es similar, agrego el nombre y el appelido en un ListBox. Pero tengo otro módulo que reacciona cuando hago doble clic en uno de los nombres-appelidos. Esto crea un UserForm con todos los resultados del candidato cuyo nombre hice clic. Sin embargo, **¿cómo transferir toda la información a este UserForm sin rehacer una búsqueda desde el nombre y el appelido (que puede presentar duplicados)?**

```
' Método que agrega los resultados de la búsqueda de "cond" en un ListBox
Sub searchresults()
    ' Miramos desde la línea 2 hasta el final de la hoja.
    For ligne = 2 To Sheets("RECAP").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row

        ' algunas condiciones que permite hacer una lista de las personas que parece ser vinculadas
        cond_function = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2) Like "*" & cboFunction & "*"
        ...
        cond_nextvsa = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 28) Like "*" & txtNextVsaReservist & "*"   

        ' probamos si las celdas están cerca de la derecha o la izquierda de los datos escritos en los campos de búsqueda
        If cond_function And cond_surname And cond_name And cond_sex And cond_rank And cond_bsn And cond_birthdate And cond_age And cond_birthplace And cond_address And cond_zipcode And cond_city And cond_telephone And cond_email And cond_contact And cond_job And cond_esr And cond_contractlength And cond_endesr And cond_sav1 And cond_sav1comment And cond_retraining And cond_fma Then
            ' Los resultados de ListBox se llenan con los nombres y apellidos del personal
            ListBoxResults.AddItem Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) & " " & Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) ' Quiero poner todos los elementos en la celda de esa manera si hacemos clic en todo está disponible
        End If                 

    Next
End Sub
```

Esto funciona con la siguiente UserForm de busqueda:

[image: la interfaz de busqueda]

Aqui esta el modulo que reacciona Cuando hago doble clic en uno de los nombres-appelidos.

```
Private Sub ListBoxResults_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim newInstanceOfMe As Object

    ' Buscamos el nombre del reservista al que hicimos clic.
    For i = 0 To ListBoxResults.ListCount - 1
        If ListBoxResults.Selected(i) Then
            ReservistName = ListBoxResults.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    ' Tenga en cuenta el caso en el que hacemos clic en los Resultados de TextBox mientras este está vacío
    If False Then
        If ReservistName <> "" Then
            Set newInstanceOfMe = UserForms.Add(Me.Name)

            newInstanceOfMe.Caption = ReservistName
            newInstanceOfMe.Show

            Unload newInstanceOfMe
            Set newInstanceOfMe = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    ReservistFormUserForm.Caption = ReservistName

    ReservistFormUserForm.Show


End Sub
```

Es para anadirlo al siguiente UserForm:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Para ayudar a reproducir

Aqui esta un extracto de la hoja excel

```
ROLE    NOM         PRENOM  SEXE    GRADE   N° INC  N° BSN  Date de naissance   Ages    LIEU NAISSANCE  ADRESSE DE REPLI    C.P VILLE   N° de Tel   N° de Tel 2 Adresse électronique (e-mail)   Personne à prévenir PROFESSION  Début ESR   duree contrat   Fin ESR SAV1    SAV1 comment    RECYCLAGE   FMA CA  VSA PROCHAINE VSA   NBR DISPO N-1   NBR GARDES N-1  NBR DISPO N NBR GARDES N    Formé ECG   MATRICULE   DU (j/m/a)  AU (j/m/a)
  CA    Hernandes   Miguel  M       CCH     31       42     29/01/88            28      Madrid          35 rue du FSH       75008       0144513100              ambassadeur@roy.uk              su esposa   ...
```

Comment: Perdona no me queda claro la duda . Lo que tienes es un metodo que obtiene los resutlados a partir de un excel y lo que quieres es que cuando creas el nuevo UserForm  no vuelva a buscar en el excel si no que use los datos que ya tienes?

Comment: @Capt.Teach Sí exactamente. Obtiene todos los datos, pero solo extrae dos (el nombre y el appelido) que transmite a un ListBox (que agregaré la captura de pantalla para que sea más claro). Cuando hace clic en un nombre y el apellido en la ListBox, ya no tengo nada que transmitir, así que tengo que rehacer una búsqueda de este nombre de apellido.

Comment: Has pensado en guardar la informacion que obtienes del Excel?. Me explico , si lees todo el excel pero solo guardas el nombre y apellido en tu listBox y luego necesitas todos los datos para mostrarlos en tu UserForm. ¿Por que no guardas toda la informacion del excel en una Lista<InformacionUsuario> (por ejemplo)? A partir de ahi en tu listbox haces un informacionUsuario.nombre/apellido y luego cuando quieras lanzar el UserForm buscas en tu lista y le pasas el objeto en concreto a mostrar.

Comment: @Capt.Teach Me parece una excellente idea, pero no sé cómo almacenar esta Lista<InformacionUsuario> en cada línea para cada persona sin mostrarla. Solo sé cómo mostrar toda la información en un ListBox y luego leerla.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias abordar este problema de la siguiente manera:

1. Creas un objeto de nombre a tu gusto por ejemplo `InformacionUsuario`, con las variables que necesites o veas relevantes.
2. Cuando leeas tu excel, vas a crear una istancia de `InformacionUsuario` y le vas a ir mapeando los campos del excel a tu clase(de la misma forma que los has obtenido Nombre y Apellido para el listBox por ejemplo). Al finalizar cada vuelta de tu bucle guardas esa istancia de `InformacionUsuario` en una lista.
3. Cuando termines de rellenar esta lista la puedes pasar o guardar en tu `form` principal o padre como una variable global(Si la haces global te sera mas facil luego utilizara desde varios sitios)
4. Una vez tienes la lista en la variable global , para rellenar tu `listBox` simplemente creas un bucle que recorra esa lista y que obtenga su nombre y su apellido  `ListBoxResults.AddItem(lista.Item(i).getNombre/getApellido)`
5. Para la parte de UserForm cuando lo llames ,puedes pasarle el nombre y apellido y en el Load que filtre la lista a partir de esos campos obteniendo el objeto `InformacionUsuario`. Una vez tengas la informacion de ese usuario lo siguiente sera mapear la informacion a los textBox correspondientes.

Esta es la forma en la que yo lo haria , no es la unica buena seguro que hay más. Pero creo que es un punto de partida para que puedes ir avanzando. Cualquier duda que te surja no dudes en preguntarle a la comunidad de StackOverflowES con el codigo que hayas intentado.

EDIT: Como pasar informacion del `FormPrincipal` al `FormHijo`

No hace falta almacenar los objetos en el `ListBox`, puedes  hacer la busqueda cuando vayas a crear el nuevo form y enviarle el objeto InformacionUsuario entero.

Codigo del UserForm:

```
public class UserForm
{

   public InformacionUsuario infoUsuario{ get; set; }
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     // Mapeas tus TextBox a los valores del objeto InformacionUsuario





   }
}
```

Codigo del FormPrincipal:

```
// El evento que genere el nuevo form
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // 1º Como tienes el nombre completo y lo que quieres es obtener un nombre y un apellido , puedes usar un split() que divida tu cadena. Esto implica que en tu listBox cuando hayas guardado los nombres y apellidos los hayas separado por una "," por ejemplo : Perez Delgado , Juan Manuel. De todas maneras seguro que encuentras la forma que mejor solucione tu problema

      // 2º Como ya tienes Nombre y Apellido simplemente es filtrar la listaUsuarios en busca del usuario objetivo y te guardas en que posicion esta

    UserForm form = new UserForm();

    form.infoUsuario =ListaUsuarios(posicion)
    form.Show();

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy en la última parte. Como pasar el nombre y apellido al UserForm ? Los muestro en el ListBox con `ListBoxResults.AddItem (arrayOReservists (i) .Surname & "" & arrayOReservists (i) .Name)` Especialmente porque cuando busco el nombre y el apellido de la persona a la que hice clic en `ListBoxResults_DblClick` con `If ListBoxResults.Selected (i) Then ReservistName = ListBoxResults.List (i)` es una cadena, y no dos objetos que posiblemente podría pasar como parámetros si supiera hacer.

Comment: Entonces mi verdadero problema es saber cómo almacenar objetos en ListBox vba y recuperarlos cuando hacemos clic sobre ellos. Luego puedo ponerlos en una variable global a la que tendré acceso en el UserForm

Comment: estoy elaborando una modificacion a mi respuesta, en unos minutos la publico. Te es mucho inconveniente si el codigo que te muestro es en C# ya que lo tengo mas fresco?

Comment: No, ya que es traducible en VBA. Nunca hice C # :)